# Cast fields of object keeping nullability

Tags: typescript, types, casting, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a type `DateToNumber` that casts all the `Date` properties of an object to `number`. This is what I have for now:

```
type LiteralDateToNumber<T> = T extends Date
  ? number
  : T extends Date | null
  ? number | null
  : T extends Date | undefined
  ? number | undefined
  : T extends Date | null | undefined
  ? number | null | undefined
  : T;

/**
 * @description Converts all `Date` properties to `number`.
 */
type DateToNumber<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: LiteralDateToNumber<T[K]>;
};
```

I want to preserve the `nullability`, here all the checks with `| null` or `| undefined`.

This mostly works, but there is an issue when using another type than `Date` that is nullable :

```
type MyType = {
  aDate: Date;
  aString: string;
  bDate: Date | null;
  bString: string | null;
  cDate: Date | undefined;
  cString: string | undefined;
  dDate: Date | null | undefined;
  dString: string | null | undefined;
  eDate?: Date;
  eString?: string;
  fDate?: Date | null;
  fString?: string | null;
  gDate?: Date | undefined;
  gString?: string | undefined;
  hDate?: Date | null | undefined;
  string?: string | null | undefined;
};
type MyCastedType = DateToNumber<MyType>;
```

In that case, `MyCastedType` is equivalent to:

```
type MyCastedType = {
  aDate: number;
  aString: string;
  bDate: number | null;
  bString: string | number | null;
  cDate: number | undefined;
  cString: string | number | undefined;
  dDate: number | null | undefined;
  dString: string | number | null | undefined;
  eDate?: number | undefined;
  eString?: string | number | undefined;
  fDate?: number | null | undefined;
  fString?: string | number | null | undefined;
  gDate?: number | undefined;
  gString?: string | number | undefined;
  hDate?: number | null | undefined;
  hString?: string | number | null | undefined;
};
```

which has several issues, I would like it to be equivalent to:

```
type MyCastedType = {
  aDate: number;
  aString: string;
  bDate: number | null;  // And not `bString: string | number | null;`
  bString: string | null;
  cDate: number | undefined;
  cString: string | undefined;  // And not `cString: string | number | undefined;`
  dDate: number | null | undefined;
  dString: string | null | undefined; // And not `dString: string | number | null | undefined;`
  eDate?: number; // And not `eDate?: number | undefined;`
  eString?: string; // And not `eString?: string | number | undefined;`
  fDate?: number | null;  // And not `fDate?: number | null;`
  fString?: string | null; // And not `fString?: string | number | null | undefined;`
  gDate?: number | undefined;
  gString?: string | undefined; // And not `gString?: string | number | undefined;`
  hDate?: number | null | undefined;
  string?: string | null | undefined; // And not `hString?: string | number | null | undefined;`
};
```

How can I implement this `DateToNumber` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simplify LiteralDateToNumber to:

```
type LiteralDateToNumber<T> = T extends Date ? number : T;
```

When you provide a type union to a generic, it will actually distribute it

```
type A = LiteralDateToNumber<Date | null>;
// is equivalent to
type B = LiteralDateToNumber<Date> | LiteralDateToNumber<null>;

// => number | null
```

The issue with your `LiteralDateToNumber` is that union used as condition will also be used distributively

```
type A<T> = T extends Date| null ? number : T;
// is equivalent to saying if T extends either Date or null (not exactly Date | null)
// => equivalent to
type B<T> = T extends Date ? number : T extends null ? number : T;

type Test = Test<null>;
// => null does extends Date | null
// => number;
```